# Create waterfall chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem. I want to create a waterfall chart. But Unfortunately it does not look correctly what I want. For example the numbers are not correctly placed and the text is missing at the end. And beside it want to create a line, that it shows more the waterfall.

How can I create the waterfall chart more what I want?

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Market': ['EU', 'EU', 'US', 'US', 'CN'],
    'Vehicle ID': ['001-1234', '001-1254', '003-7485', '001-1232', '001-2138'],
    'Status': ['Rec.', 'Rec.', 'Development', 'Stopped', 'Development']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


filtered_df = df[df['Vehicle ID'].str.startswith('001')]


status_order = [
    'Wachting', 'Stopped', 'Development', 'Rec.',
]

status_counts = filtered_df['Status'].value_counts().reindex(status_order, fill_value=0)


total_count = df.shape[0]


status_counts = status_counts.append(pd.Series({'Total': total_count})).reindex(['Total'] + status_order)

plt.bar(status_counts.index, status_counts)
plt.xlabel('Status')
plt.ylabel('Number of Vehicles')
plt.title('Distribution of Vehicle Status for vehicles starting with "001"')


for index, value in enumerate(status_counts):
    plt.text(index, -0.1, str(value), ha='center')


plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In the bottom figure, *Watching, Stopped* and *Development* all start at the top. Rec. is by itself at the bottom. It looks like you are grouping them in some way before generating the bottom plot?

Comment: Without inspection of the code, what comes into my mind at first sight is that in the second chart the sum in Total is not correct (4 instead of 5).

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the calculation of the values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'orders':[4, 0, -1, -1, -2], 
                   'names':['Total', 'Wachting', 'Stopped', 'Development', 'Rec.']})
colors = df.orders.apply(lambda x: 'green' if x>0 else 'red')
bottom = df.orders.cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)
gap = bottom.reset_index(drop=True).repeat(3).shift(-1)
gap[1::3] = np.nan  # create gaps 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_plot = df.plot.bar(x='names', y='orders', legend=None, bottom=bottom,title="Waterfall", color=colors, ax=ax)
my_plot.plot(gap.index, gap.values,'k')

my_plot.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='center')
my_plot.set_ylim(-1,7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your question, but if you just want to make a waterfall graph that has lines rather than bars you can replace

```
plt.bar(status_counts.index, status_counts)
```

with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.step(
    status_counts.index, status_counts, label="Waterfall", where="mid", color="blue"
)
```

You can replace "where" argument with "pre" and "post" to show the numbers at the start and the end respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your preferred visualization library is matplotlib, but plotly has the ability to draw waterfall graphs. Based on your data, I have created a code based on the examples in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/waterfall-charts/#setting-marker-size-and-color) to match your final output.
I set the total as the measurement as absolute values and the rest as relative values. This answer is just my suggestion and I hope it helps you in your visualization.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Waterfall(
    name='',
    orientation='v',
    measure=['absolute','relative','relative','relative','relative'],
    x=status_counts.index.tolist(),
    textposition='outside',
    text=['Total','0','1','1','2'],
    y=[4,0,-1,-1,-2],
    connector=dict(line=dict(color='rgb(63, 63, 63)'))
))

fig.update_layout(
    title='Distribution of Vehicle Status for vehicles starting with "001"',
    showlegend=False
)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[-1,5])
fig.show()
```

[image]